# Modal + passive voice usage

Tags: modal-verbs, passive-voice

I would like to use a sentence like

> It should be being sold at somewhere for an affordable price.

Would it be syntactically correct ?

Comment: We don't use *at somewhere*. The item can be bought somewhere, because I know it's sold somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it seems better without the first  *at*.

> It should be being sold  somewhere for an affordable price.

This is syntactically correct, but it's certainly an uncommon way to get the thought across.

You can, of course, just say:

> It should be for sale somewhere at an affordable price.

Note, you can also use the present perfect passive with a modal:

> It should have been being  sold somewhere at an affordable place,  that way I could have bought it when I needed it.

but there are less convoluted ways to express the same thought. Note also that some native speakers may find either your construction or mine marginally correct, and some may find it to be of doubtful usage, or say it is not syntactically correct.  It really does come down to *what sounds right* to the individual, and in the individual sentences,  in cases like these.

Comment: Note that I edited my answer to say that the sentence sounds better without the first *at*.